# Angular Material 2 md-tab content height

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I'm new to angular material and I'm trying to implement md-tab into my app.
But, I'm not able to style my tab content to acquire the remaining height of the screen. Could anyone please look into the plunker and point out where am I going wrong?
Following is the link to plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/gfKhz3IcMjPHS7F8Up50?p=preview
**tabs-overview-example.html**

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab label="Tab 1"><div class="content-style">Content 1</div></md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

**tabs-overview-example.css**

```
html{
  height:100%;
}
body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  overflow: auto;
}
md-tab-group{
  height: 100%;
}
.content-style {
  height: 100%;
  background-color:#fffbda;
}
```

**tabs-overview-example.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'tabs-overview-example',
  templateUrl: './tabs-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabs-overview-example.css']
})
export class TabsOverviewExample {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of vh: 1vh is equal to 1% height. That is to say, 100vh is equal to the height of the browser window 100%, regardless of where the element is situated in the DOM tree:

`.content-style {
  height:100vh;
  background-color:#fffbda;
}`

reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like the content to acquire the remaining space without defining number of pixels, would rather prefer height in %. Is there a way I can achieve that?

Comment: @NikitSrivastava I have updated my answer, check that ;)